# WPF FlowDocument to InlineCollection

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, textblock, flowdocument

I want to create a small in Place Editor in a WPF Application for TextBox Texts. For this I want to use the RichTextBox. As the RichTextBox works with a FlowDocument, and the TextBlock with a InlineCollection, this does not work. Is there a easy way to Convert the RichtextBox Document to a InlineCollection? (If I only allow RTB Content wich is supported in a Inline?)

Comment: You want to use RichTextBox, so all you need is a `FlowDocument`. Why do you want to convert that to some InlineCollection?

Comment: I want to use RichTextBox for edit! Later I want to Display the Text in a TextBlock

Comment: the `FlowDocument` is fairly complicated, it contains a mix of BlockCollection and InlineCollection as well as other stuff (not common but may have). So I don't think this is the right approach. Converting may require some extra code and running it may require much time depending on your document. My advice is just use one of the following controls instead of TextBlock: `RichTextBox`, `FlowDocumentReader`, `DocumentViewer`, `FlowDocumentPageViewer`, `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`. For `RichTextBox`, you can set its `IsReadOnly` to `true` to use it as a presenter/viewer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like the following extension method could be used to extract all Inlines from a FlowDocument. You might need to add some extra whitespace inlines to separate the paragraphs and sections.

```
public static class FlowDocumentEx
{
    public static ICollection<Inline> GetInlines(this FlowDocument doc)
    {
        return GetInlines(doc.Blocks);
    }

    public static ICollection<Inline> GetInlines(TextElementCollection<Block> blocks)
    {
        var inlines = new List<Inline>();

        foreach (var block in blocks)
        {
            if (block is Paragraph)
            {
                inlines.AddRange(((Paragraph)block).Inlines);
            }
            else if (block is Section)
            {
                inlines.AddRange(GetInlines(((Section)block).Blocks));
            }
        }

        return inlines;
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
textBlock.Inlines.AddRange(richTextBox.Document.GetInlines());
```

Comment: Works Perfect.

I use it to implement a Formatted Text Editor for TextBlock Content in Sharp Develop!